# how to implement std::Vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())

Tags: c++11, vector, stl

I am trying to rewrite c++ std::vector according exactly to the STL interface: the following is what I did in my vector.h file

vector.h

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
namespace ting{
template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator <T>>
class Vector{
using value_type = T;
using allocator_type = Alloc;
using reference = value_type&;
using const_reference = const value_type&;
using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer;
using const_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::const_pointer;
using size_type = std::size_t;
using iterator = std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, value_type>;
using const_iterator = const iterator;
using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
private:
    pointer data;
    size_type size;
    size_type capacity;
    allocator_type alloc;
public:
    explicit Vector(const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()):alloc(alloc){size = 0; capacity = 0;}
    Vector(size_type n, const value_type& val, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()):size(n),capacity(n),alloc(alloc){
        data = new T[size];
        for(size_type i =0; i<size;i++){
             data[i] = val;
        }
    }
//don't know how to implement
    template< class InputIt>
    Vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()){
        size = capacity = difference_type(last - first);
        data = new value_type[size];
        InputIt temp;
        size_type  i;
        for(temp = first, i = 0;temp!=last; temp++,i++){
            data[i] = *temp;
        }
    }

    ~Vector(){ delete []data;}
//......
};
};
```

while I build: I got the following compiling error:

> /home/ting/Proj/vector_test/vector.h:44: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
>                data[i] = *temp;
>                          ^~~~~

Can anyone give me an example of how to implement this constructor?

Comment: It seems like you're getting a call to your iterator-based constructor on integer arguments. I'm guessing that you said something like `Vector<int> v(137, 42)` and it's triggering that constructor rather than the value-based one you intended.

Comment: [In the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), note the remark by the overload **(4)**: "This overload only participates in overload resolution if `InputIt` satisfies `InputIterator`, to avoid ambiguity with the overload **(2)**." This doesn't come for free, it takes some SFINAE trickery.